# ubuntu 22.04 jammy oibaf broken package

Tags: drivers, package-management, 22.04

I installed ppa for oibaf then I got broken package during installation. Please help me to fix it...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j is installed
```

Now I cannot revert back with ppa purge because it is trying to remove most of OS packages including gnome applications.

Here is the apt history while installing oibaf packages:

```
Start-Date: 2022-04-29  01:18:24
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Requested-By: ahmety (1000)
Install: libllvm14:amd64 (1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1, automatic)
Upgrade: libcurl4:amd64 (7.81.0-1, 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.1), networkd-dispatcher:amd64 (2.1-2, 2.1-2ubuntu0.22.04.1), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.81.0-1, 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), libgbm1:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), libcurl4-gnutls-dev:amd64 (7.81.0-1, 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.1), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.110+git2204220500.d95b12~oibaf~j), libxatracker2:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), libvdpau1:amd64 (1.4-3build2, 1.5-1~oibaf~j), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.110+git2204220500.d95b12~oibaf~j), vdpau-driver-all:amd64 (1.4-3build2, 1.5-1~oibaf~j), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), snapd:amd64 (2.55.3+22.04, 2.55.3+22.04ubuntu1), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.110+git2204220500.d95b12~oibaf~j), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.110+git2204220500.d95b12~oibaf~j), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.110+git2204220500.d95b12~oibaf~j), curl:amd64 (7.81.0-1, 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.1), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (22.0.1-1ubuntu2, 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j), microsoft-edge-stable:amd64 (100.0.1185.50-1, 101.0.1210.32-1), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.110-1ubuntu1, 2.4.110+git2204220500.d95b12~oibaf~j)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2022-04-29  01:18:48
```

Actually, I understand that following error is the reason of the problem:

```
dpkg: error processing archive libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so', which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 21.3.7-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j_amd64.deb
```

Comment: The jammy repo was updated this morning: `jammy/ 2022-04-29 07:36`  https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: I had the same issue with the broken package while trying to revert back and I accidentally removed all OS packages. Ubuntu now restarts only in tty mode. What do I do? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a dependency issue in the PPA right now. It doesn't distribute `libgl1-amber-dri`, but one of its packages recommends it, but there's a conflicting file. Anyway, the following should fix the issue:

```bsh
sudo dpkg --remove libgl1-amber-dri
sudo apt install --fix-broken --no-install-recommends
```

We remove the bad package with `dpkg` (since `apt` will have a hard time doing things with broken dependencies). Then, we let `apt` fix itself, but tell it not to install recommended packages.